# Should a phrasal adjective be hyphenated when its modifier is omitted?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

With modifier:
We were going on an air-to-air photo mission.

Without:
We were going on our first air to air.

OR

We were going on our first air-to-air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should stay hyphenated, I think. It's still a phrasal adjective, modifying a noun that is now implied; it just turns into a [nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective) when the noun is removed.

Note that it's the adjectives that modify the noun here, not vice versa. Unless I misunderstood what you mean by modifier.